# word to latex citation

Tags: bibliographies

Good afternoon !

Suppose that we have those citations from word :

```
[1] Yang, Xin-She - Optimization techniques and applications with examples-John Wiley & Sons (2018)

[2] (Frontiers in applied mathematics) C. T. Kelley - Iterative Methods for Optimization-Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics (1987)

[3] Marco Cavazzuti (auth.) - Optimization Methods_ From Theory to Design Scientific and Technological Aspects in Mechanics-Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg (2013)
```

I'm searching a quick way to convert them in latex format ( ex : free online service , converter ... ).

Thank you for help !

Comment: What do you mean "citations from Word"? Written out by whoever wrote the text, loaded from some citation source (database, etc), other? (Sorry, I don't use Word for more than very occasional short, simple documents, so...)

Comment: @vonbrand ; the problem is already solved as shown by the answer below. I was searching a way to convert citations from APA format to bibtex format. I had found two solutions : using google scholar or using the tool below for finding matches.

Comment: @vonbrand  , Thank you for your comment !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this tool is good for the wanted job :

https://citation-finder.now.sh/

Also it's possible to use google scholar !
You could close the question !